# Pinvoking a native function with array arguments

Tags: c#, arrays, pinvoke

I am completely confused with how to go about calling functions in native dll with array arguments.

Example:

The function is defined in the C# project as:

```
[DllImport("Project2.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern void modifyArray([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] int[] x, int len);
```

And the function call is:

```
modifyArray(arr, 3)
```

where arr = {4,5,6}

The native C++ function definition is as follows:

```
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) void modifyArray(int* x,int len)
{   
        int arr[] = {1,2,3};
        x = arr;
}
```

Why in the C# project, the array is not pointing to the new array after the function call? It still remains {4,5,6}.

I tried this to but failed

```
[DllImport("Project2.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern void modifyArray([In,Out] int[] x, int len);
```

This pinvoke fails whenever I try modifying arguments passed to these functions using pointers. Otherwise, I have had success passing ref array arguments for native dll sort functions where there is no pointer changes to newly created types.

Comment: Your C++ code is invalid, don't try to pinvoke code until you've got it working in C++ first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your C++ code is broken. The caller allocates the array, and the callee populates it. Like this:

```
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) void modifyArray(int* x, int len)
{   
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
        x[i] = i;
}
```

As far as your p/invoke call goes, `SetLastError` should not be `true`. The function is not calling `SetLastError`. It should be:

```
[DllImport("Project2.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern void modifyArray(int[] x, int len);
```

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with PInvoke, this is just a plain old C issue.  You would have the exact same problem if you called `modifyArray` from C

```
int* pArray = NULL;
modifyArray(pArray, len);
pArray == NULL;  // true!
```

In `modifyArray` you are trying to change where `x` points to.  This change won't be visible to the calling function because the pointer is passed by value.  In order to change where it points to you need to pass a double pointer

```
void modifyArray(int** x, int len) { 
  *x = ...;
}
```

Note that you are currently trying to return stack allocated memory instead of heap allocated memory.  That is incorrect and will lead to problems down the line

Comment: This gets him into a *lot* more trouble, best to recommend him to copy the elements instead.

Comment: I wrote this as a sample code, but the c++ code is much more complex and I can't modify it. So, I think what JaredPar answered will be best in my case.
But, when I tried this, with changing the argument type to ref int[], it failed

Comment: That is, how should modifyArray be defined in the C# file

Comment: I did modify the C++ code, but only the first element of the array gets modified, I think to the address of the array in the C++ function.

Comment: In addition, even when using a "double pointer", never pass a pointer to something allocated on the stack out of the function - it will be undefined where it points to later...

Comment: In that case, mihi, in the C++ function, how do I modify the memory location the C# array points to

Comment: And of course he [did get in trouble](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20911281/pinvoking-a-function-that-needs-to-modify-an-array-argument).