# Getting the size of the array pointed to by IntPtr

Tags: c#, pinvoke, intptr

I have a native C++ function that I call from a C# project using pinvoke.

```
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) void GetCmdKeyword( wchar_t** cmdKeyword, uint  pCmdNum )
{
 int status = 1;
 int       count     = 0;
 int       i         = 0;

 if( cmdKeyword == NULL )
      return ERR_NULL_POINTER;

 //search command in command list by letter from 'A' to 'Z'
 count = sizeof( stCommandList ) / sizeof( COMMANDLIST ) ;

 for ( i = 0 ; i < count && status != 0; i++ )
 {
      if ( pCmdNum != stCommandList[i].ulCommand )
           continue;
      *cmdKeyword = &stCommandList[i].CommandKeyWord[0];
      status = 0 ;
 }
```

}

where stCommandList is a strucutre of type COMMANDLIST and CommandKeyWord member is a char array.

To call this function from C#, I need to pass what arguments? cmdKeyword should be populated in a char array or a string on the C# side i.e. I need to copy the contents of the location that ptr is pointing to an int array in C# file. If I knew the length, I could use Marshal.Copy to do the same. How can I do it now? Also, I do not wish to use unsafe.
Does [Globalsize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366593.aspx) help in this?

Comment: Without more information on `fun`'s interface, there is no way of knowing. You can't use GlobalSize if you're not 100% sure the memory is allocated with GlobalAlloc(). If you know more about `fun`, there might be an hint, such as a sentinel value.

Comment: this is why almost every c++ function that takes an array pointer *also* takes an array length.  there's no way to know!

Comment: What you should do is allocate the array in the managed code and pass it to the native code to let the native code populate it. For int elements that is int[] on the managed side and int* on the native side. I'd be very surprised if int** was the right solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot infer the length from the pointer. The information must be passed as a separate value alongside the pointer to the array.

I wonder why you use raw `IntPtr` rather than C# arrays. I think the answer you accepted to your earlier question has the code that you need: [Pinvoking a native function with array arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20909900/pinvoking-a-native-function-with-array-arguments).

---

OK, looking at the edit to the question, the actual scenario is a little different. The function returns a pointer to a null-terminated array of wide characters. Your pinvoke should be:

```
[DllImport(...)]
static extern void GetCmdKeyword(out IntPtr cmdKeyword, uint pCmdNum);
```

Call it like this:

```
IntPtr ptr;
GetCmdKeyword(ptr, cmdNum);
string cmdKeyword = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(ptr);
```

Comment: Sorry, it was int array. I used IntPtr instead of c# array because in your earlier answer, if I needed to get the new memory location that a pointer was pointing to in the C++ function, I need to call it using an out IntPtr and not a ref int[]

Comment: Oh no, now I'm confusing you. Yes, on the native side int*  Now removed offending comment. I think the answer has it right.

Comment: I am being patient I think. Don't use `ref ushort[]`. And don't use `int**`. That's got too much indirection. And you cannot expect native code to make a new `ushort[]`. Use the code from my answer your other question that is linked from my answer here. You simply should not be expecting the native code to allocate the array. Who is going to free it?

Comment: True. Your code will work had the native C++ argument been wchar_t*. But it is wchar_t** and modifying the C++ function is not an option for me

Comment: What is the variable? Pointer to pointer to array of characters, null terminated? And if so, how is the allocation done. Static or off the heap? If the latter, how is caller meant to deallocate? If my assumption above re variable type meaning is accurate then it's passed as out IntPtr ptr and you read the value with Marshal.PtrToStringUni(ptr)

Comment: That's it. Marshal.PtrToStringUni(ptr). Thanks! Have a good weekend

Comment: Tell me about the allocation. Who is going to free the string?

Comment: Isn't the allocation done by String result = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(ptr);

Comment: No. I mean the native memory. The wchar_t* that is returned. Is it static, or heap allocated? If the latter, there is more work to do.

Comment: OK, I've just seen the question edit. The strings are not dynamically allocated. PtrToStringUni is all you need.

Comment: It is static on the native C++ side. Not on the heap.

Comment: If it was on the heap, what else would have been require\d?

Comment: That depends. The C++ runtime heap would need the native code to export a deallocator. Or, a shared heap like COM heap or GlobalAlloc would allow caller to deallocate.

Answer (score 0):

> You cannot infer the length from the pointer.

You can absolutely do that on a Windows platform as long as the pointer was allocated using [`GlobalAlloc()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-globalalloc), [`LocalAlloc()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-localalloc), or [`HeapAlloc()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/heapapi/nf-heapapi-heapalloc) API (though the latter is a bit more complicated).

**IMPORTANT:** *Keep in mind that the size of a memory block may be larger than the size requested when the memory was allocated.*

Here is an example on how to find memory block size allocated using [`Marshal.AllocHGlobal()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.allochglobal?view=net-6.0)  or [`Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtohglobaluni?view=net-6.0), which both internally use `LocalAlloc()`:

```
namespace HGlobalSizeTest
{
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    internal static class WinAPI
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern UIntPtr LocalSize(IntPtr hMem);

        internal static UInt64 HGlobalSize(IntPtr hMem)
        {
            return LocalSize(hMem).ToUInt64();
        }
    }

    internal static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string TestString = "Test string!\0With embedded null character!";

            IntPtr TestStringPtr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(TestString);

            UInt64 cb = WinAPI.HGlobalSize(TestStringPtr);

            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(TestStringPtr);

            Console.WriteLine($"    TestString length = {TestString.Length}");
            Console.WriteLine($" TestStringPtr  bytes = {cb}");
            Console.WriteLine($" TestStringPtr length = {cb >> 1}");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Code meant for demonstration purposes only, all error checking omitted for brevity. Do not use as-is in production.

Finally, note that `GlobalAlloc()` and `LocalAlloc()` are both deprecated in favor of `HeapAlloc` which has considerably less overhead so this is of very limited use in practice and it is always prudent to pass the actual unmanaged memory size as a parameter where knowing the unmanaged memory size is necessary.

Comment: There are a lot of questions you could have posted this answer to.  Too bad you picked one where this hack is very unlikely to work.

Comment: @HansPassant The only reason I even posted it is because the accepted answer claims that "You cannot infer the length from the pointer" which is technically correct and meant to discourage such usage pattern, but it is also factually incorrect at least on Windows platform. All Windows memory management APIs allow for querying the memory block size, and even in plain C you can use [`_msize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/msize?view=vs-2019) API to get the size of the memory block allocated with `malloc`, `calloc`, and `realloc`.